# Css For Gridview paging

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

My question is, can I control the style of the paging element separately of top and bottom, I have set the paging to appear in both top and bottom of the gridview, and I want to see that the top pagination is little high up in the page, to do that I used the cssClass and set margin-top:20px and made the position: absolute, this does change the position of the top paging area and set it rightly for me, but the bottom pagination has also come up as a result and now sits inside the grid data!! Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you adjust your CSS, not the style associated with the GridView.  Figure out what is causing the space that you want to negate, and eliminate that.  Negative css margins is really unnecessary.

If you can't figure out what is causing the space, use FireFox with FireBug.  Right click the area, select "Inspect Element".  A couple windows will open... one with the html that is selected, and another showing the CSS that is effective in that area.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to keep a different stylesheet for the bottompagerrow, and I have done it like this in the page load

```vb
Dim prow As GridViewRow
prow = GridView1.BottomPagerRow
prow.CssClass = "BottompagerRowStyle"
```

Since this page will always have data, I did not bother to check for the existence of the bottompager, which can be done additionally